# Python iterating over a list to add items to another list?

Tags: python, mysql, list, sqlalchemy, flask

So I am getting a list of items from a MySQL database, working with Python, Flask, Flask-SQLAlchemy. I am already incrementing rows of this list like this:

```
for file in files:
        file.last_viewed_time = datetime.utcnow()
    db.session.commit()
```

But I want to extract one more thing from this list (files),  a list of another attribute. 
How can I add these to a new list, something like:

```
mylist = []

for file in files:
        new = file.attribute
        add new to mylist
```

Or is this a convoluted way of doing it, can I copy these values in a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`list.append`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#mutable-sequence-types):

```
mylist = []

for f in files:
    new = f.attribute
    mylist.append(new)
```

Or using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
mylist = [f.attribute for f in files]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one question: Can I call a function from within a list declaration? I would like to get a list of urls, would something like this worK? 
'linklist = [url_for(f.filename) for f in files]'

Comment: @neal, Yes, you can. You can use any *expression* there.

Comment: @neal, If you follow the link in the answer, there's more kind explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = [f.attribute for f in files] # don't use file, it's the name of a builtin-function
```

Comment: File is not a *keyword*, but [a builtin function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) (Only in Python 2.x)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mylist = []

for file in files:
        new = file.attribute
        mylist.append(new)
```